# How to change the default url for 'Posts' link?

Tags: admin, urls, admin-menu

I would like to change the default url `edit.php` to `edit.php?category_name=photos` when I click on "Articles".

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below code should help you.

```
function myadminurl() {
// generate url path to Posts -> Categories page in the admin and force http
$url = admin_url( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category', 'http' );
echo $url;
}
add_action( 'init', 'myadminurl' );
```

Please refer this [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/admin_url) for more information.